# How to ask what days of the week someone does something

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, particle-へ

How would I ask some "What days of the week do you go to school?"
Would "なんようび、がっこうへいきますか" be a correct translation?

Comment: なんようびに would be a better grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> "What days of the week do you go to school?"
>   →Would "なんようび、がっこうへいきますか" be a correct translation?

Correct! 　And, 「なんようびに」that is commented by boccoli forest is better.
If the questioner knows that you go to school mulitiple times in a week, the natural ways of asking are;

> - なんようとなんように、がっこうへいきますか？
> - がっこうへいくの、なんようとなんようなの？